# Pass variable from Devise controller to custom mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I use Devise for authentication in my Rails app.

In my `registrations_controller` I have a variable like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    foo = "bar"
    super
  end
end
```

In my customized mailer I then try to access the `foo` variable. The `opts` argument seems to be the one to look at:

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    Rails.logger.error opts[:foo].inspect
    super
  end
end
```

But how do I pass on the `foo` variable on, without overwriting a lot of methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read about [Devise custom mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Use-custom-mailer) to familiarize yourself with the process.

Briefly this is how you'd go about doing it:

in config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.mailer = "DeviseMailer"
```

Now you can just use DeviseMailer like you'd do for any other mailer in your project:

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
     ...

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"
    opts[:from] = 'my_custom_from@domain.com'
    opts[:reply_to] = 'my_custom_from@domain.com'
    super
  end

      ...
   end
```

You can now call the `confirmation_instructions` in your project and pass whatever variable you want to be able to access in your template.

i.e:

Calling the `confirmation_instructions` method:

```
 DeviseMailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, "faketoken", {})
```

confirmation_instructions.html.erb

```
 <p> And then override the template according to you. <p>
```

Hope this will help you :)